# Unity Inventory System: Item Stack

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stack, inventory

Hi guys im just wondering if whats the problem of my code. it can add first item with stacks but it stops at adding second item with stack. Please kindly help

```
void AddItems ()
{
    Item itemToAdd = itemDatabase.items[0];

    if (IsInInventory(itemToAdd))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventoryItems.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inventoryItems[i].item == itemToAdd )
            {
                if (inventoryItems[i].item.isStackable)
                {
                    if (inventoryItems[i].stackSize != inventoryItems[i].item.stackSize)
                    {
                        inventoryItems[i].stackSize++;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            else if (inventoryItems[i].item == itemToAdd && inventoryItems[i].stackSize > itemToAdd.stackSize)
            {
                AddItem(itemToAdd);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AddItem(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly, that you cant add an Item to an existing stack, its propably due to this if condition:

```
    if (inventoryItems[i].item == itemToAdd )
```

If this should work, you need to override the "Equals" and "GetHashCode" Method in your Item class, since default "==" operator just checks if the reference are equal

Comment: i can add item to an existing item stack, but whenever that item stack is full its not adding new item

Answer (score 0):

Many Errors. isStackable checked to late. Addition to stack of item only one.

```
if (inventoryItems[i].item == itemToAdd ) {}
else if (inventoryItems[i].item == itemToAdd && inventoryItems[i].stackSize > itemToAdd.stackSize) {}
```

else never happen

```
void AddItems () {
    Item itemToAdd = itemDatabase.items[0];
    if (inventoryItems[i].item.isStackable && IsInInventory(itemToAdd)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventoryItems.Count; i++) {
            if (inventoryItems[i].item == itemToAdd ) {
                if (inventoryItems[i].stackSize+itemToAdd.stackSize <= inventoryItems[i].item.stackSize) {
                    inventoryItems[i].stackSize += itemToAdd.stackSize;
                } else {
                    itemToAdd.stackSize -= inventoryItems[i].item.stackSize-inventoryItems[i].stackSize;
                    inventoryItems[i].stackSize = inventoryItems[i].item.stackSize;
                    AddItem(itemToAdd);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        AddItem(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```